# How do I build and run qt/qt creator on Odroid XU3?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, odroid

I want to run QT-Creator on my Odroid XU3 (ARM Architecture with Lubuntu 14.4) and build an application with it. I've read a lot of on the internet to figure out how to do this but haven't been successful yet. I tried to follow these instructions https://wiki.qt.io/ODROID-XU3 but didn't understand few things.

1. It states that I need to install some dependencies. I followed the given hyperlink on this site and installed the dependencies using following commands:

sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default

sudo apt-get install "^libxcb.*" libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev 
libxrender-dev libxi-dev

1. When I searched for my qt5 folder, I could only find qt4 in user/share. What did I do wrong?
2. It states that I have to setup a toolchain and a sysroot. Do I have to do this only if I want to cross-compile, so compile on a different machine for my Odroid XU3, or also if I just want to compile on Odroid itself?
3. Let's say I want to setup the toolchain. According to this site I should copy the raspberry pi toolchain (or a different one) into the folder ~/Code/Odroid/toolchain. Problem is I don't see such a folder in my home directory on my Odroid. Should I mkdir one? 
   Let's also say I want to setup the sysroot, I don't get the part "One is to mount the ODROID-XU3's SD Card or eMMC on your development machine and either make a copy or a link to ~/Code/Odroid/sysroot". Am I right in assuming that I should copy the content of my SD-card to this folder on my developing machine?
4. Where should I build my QT now - on my development machine or Odroid? (sorry for that stupid question)
5. What If I want to make it simple and build everything on Adroid XU3 assuming that I have plenty of time and resources. I tried to first install qt and qt creator afterwards but as I started qtcreator, there was no compiler preconfigured and also the QuickView was missing. The terminal was also mentioning that the toolchain is missing. I struggled a lot in order to add these missing components but failed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

to your second point: you can compile it on the Odroid or on your PC. But you should take a look at this: https://wiki.qt.io/Category:QtonPi it should be pretty the same on the Odroid.